How can I strengthen my application for a computer science master's program with a background in medical electronics engineering?
I'm planning to apply for a master's program in computer science at a German public university. I have a background in medical electronics engineering, a GPA of 3.9, three years of work experience, and an IELTS score of 7. However, I want to ensure that my application is as strong as possible, given my somewhat non-traditional background for a computer science degree.
My specific questions are:

How can I effectively leverage my engineering background to demonstrate my readiness for a computer science program?
Are there any particular skills or projects I should focus on to strengthen my application?
What additional steps can I take to improve my chances of acceptance into a competitive program?


I think this will be difficult without additional courses. Choose some reputable university and look at the curriculum of an undergraduate CS major there. Look at what courses are required and match your own background to that. I'll guess that there are many differences. Are you familiar with the theory of data structures and algorithms? How about the underlying theory of databases? Have you done large programming projects?
If your focus on medical device engineering was on the software side there might be fewer gaps than if you focused on hardware.
If you find such gaps, find a way to fill them with something like a course for which others can attest to your competence. Some places these courses are open in the evening so that employed people can take them (US perspective).
You can also talk to some local university about whether you could be accepted there or what gaps you would need to fill.
Other needed courses might be compiler construction and operating system theory.

I am working as a Software Engineer in a German Automotive Company. I am having a question if this work experience helps.

I am familiar with programming. I work in Software projects.

CS isn't just programming. It is much more.

Being “familiar with programming” can be a pretty low bar (i.e., that’s not a very impressive claim). And, as @Buffy says, CS is a lot more than simply programming. But yes, depending on how much experience you have in software engineering—and the depth, breadth, and quality of that experience—it could make you somewhat more appealing.

i have been in software f=engineering for almost 3 years.  i have  done my projects in AI. The concern is if i start  my application process. how relevant it can be to strengthen my application
